# Querying item that is NOT EQUAL in the second table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a newbie question about oracle Query. I want to query all the items that are not equal in 2 tables.

my tables are like this

A,

```
NAME  VAL1 VAL2
HEAD1 400  80
HEAD2 300  70
HEAD3 299  49
HEAD4 199  59
```

and table B,

```
NAME  VAL1 VAL2
HEAD1 400  80
HEAD2 300  70
HEAD3 200  60
HEAD4 100  50
```

and my query,

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.VAL1 VALUEA1, B.VAL1 VALUEB1 FROM A, B
WHERE (SELECT B.VAL1 FROM B WHERE A.VAL1 != B.VAL1)
```

and my expected output would be like this

```
NAME  VALUEA1 VALUEB1
HEAD3 299     200
HEAD4 199     100
```

Please help me with my query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select A.Name, A.VAL1 AS VALUEA1, A.VAL2 AS VALUEB1 
From TableA as A, TableB As B
Where A.NAME = B.NAME AND A.VAL2 != B.VAL2
```

Comment: Looks like `A.Val2` should be changed to `B.Val1` in the `select` statement.  And I believe OP wants `A.Val1 <> B.Val1` in the `where` criteria based on expected results.  Finally, I would suggest using the standard `JOIN` syntax as a preferable solution.

Answer (score 3):

I think a standard `JOIN` should work:

```
select a.name, a.val1, b.val1 as bval1
from a 
  join b on a.name = b.name
where a.val1 <> b.val1
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/06394/2)